# to add an input element to the form dynamically using only PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

1. I would like to add an input element to the form dynamically using only PHP.

   I know how to make this using php and JavaScript combination, thus do nto advice abotu JavaScript.

   The example below does not work. Could you please advice and comment:

   input.php

   ```
   <br> <input type="text" name="mob[]"  value="" size="3" >
   ```

   form.php

   ```
   <?php
   if( isset($_POST['AddNum']) ){
       $AddNumCount=$_POST['AddNumCount'];
       $AddNumCount=$AddNumCount+1;
       echo $AddNumCount;
   }
   if( isset($_POST['register']) ){
       print_r($_POST['register']);
   }
   if (!isset($AddNumCount)) {$AddNumCount=5;}
   ?>


   <form action="" method="post" id="form1"   action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"  >

   <br>
   <?php  for ($i=0; $i<$AddNumCount; $i++) { Include('input.php'); } ?>

   <br> Add number: <input type="submit" name="AddNum" form="form1" value="Add NUmber"> </p>
                    <input type="hidden" name="AddNumCount" form="form1" value="  <?php $AddNumCount; ?>  "> </p>

   <br></form><input type="submit" name="register" id="regcont" value="register"> </p>
   </form>
   ```
2. Maybe you know how to make single submit button for many forms?
   I mean each input would be a separare form and all forms can be submittted with the button on the end?

Comment: What exactly dont work? Do you have any errors?

Answer (score 0):

You use two `action` attrs. Maybe you mean:

```
<form method="post" id="form1" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"  >
```

For submitting many forms by one button - you need to use `JavaScript` and send them in cycle via `AJAX`.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry i change this post. This is working example for dynamical PHP.
Use EXform.php. Other files are generated or helping.
Maybe it is also possible to make this using Session variables and header for redirecting to regenerated webpage.

**EXform.php**

```
<?php if (isset( $_POST['AddNum'])) { Include("GENinput.php"); } ?>
<?php if (!isset( $_POST['AddNumCount'])) { $_POST['AddNumCount']=1; Include("GENinput.php"); } ?>


<form action="" method="post" id="form1"   action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"  >

<?php Include("INCinput.php"); ?>

<br> Add number: <input type="submit" name="AddNum" form="form1" value="Add NUmber"> </p>
                 <input type="hidden" name="AddNumCount" form="form1" value="<?php echo $AddNumCount; ?>"> </p>

<input type="submit" name="register" id="regcont" value="register"> </p>
<br></form>
</form>
```

**GENinput.php** // generates included file

```
<?php

if( isset($_POST['AddNum']) ){
    $AddNumCount=$_POST['AddNumCount']; //=
    $fnameinp="INCinput.php";
  $fileinp=fopen($fnameinp,"w");
    $_POST['AddNumCount']=$AddNumCount=$AddNumCount+1;  

    //echo "AddNumCount=".$AddNumCount;

        $strV=""; $stri="";
    for ($i=0; $i<$AddNumCount; $i++) { 
    $strV.=" \n  
        <?php 
        if( isset(\$_POST['v']['tname']['colname'][".$i."])  )
           { \$v['tname']['colname'][".$i."]=\$_POST['v']['tname']['colname'][".$i."];}
        else { \$v['tname']['colname'][".$i."]=".$i."; } 
        ?>
        ";

        $stri.=" <br> <input type=\"text\" name=\"v[tname][colname][".$i."]\"  value=\"<?php echo \$v['tname']['colname'][".$i."]; ?>\" > \n\n";

    }

    fwrite($fileinp,$strV); 
    fwrite($fileinp,$stri);
    fclose($fileinp);
}
```